# Im Getting File Not Found Exception in Filereader in linux mint

Tags: java, android, json, filereader

this is the code:

```
package com.example.def5ine;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FileReader fileReader;
    try {
        Log.d("dd", "msg");
        //FileReader("/home/likewise-open/vigneshwaranm/workspace/java/src/example/dictionary.json")

        fileReader = new FileReader("/android_asset/dictionary.json");
        jsonReader = new JsonReader(fileReader);
         jsonReader.beginObject();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Button srch=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final TextView res=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    srch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
                    String name = jsonReader.nextName();
                    if (name.equals("domain")) {
                        res.setText("ss");
                    } else {
                        jsonReader.skipValue();
                        res.setText("fail");
                    }
                }
                jsonReader.endObject();
                jsonReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }); 
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Log Cat Output:

```
12-12 07:12:26.600: D/dd(1359): msg
<b>12-12 07:12:26.600: W/System.err(1359): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android_asset/dictionary.json: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-12 07:12:26.610: W/System.err(1359):     at </b>libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
12-12 07:12:26.610: W/System.err(1359):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
12-12 07:12:26.610: W/System.err(1359):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
12-12 07:12:26.610: W/System.err(1359):     at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
12-12 07:12:26.620: W/System.err(1359):     at com.example.def5ine.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
12-12 07:12:26.620: W/System.err(1359):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
12-12 07:12:26.620: W/System.err(1359):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-12 07:12:26.620: W/System.err(1359):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
12-12 07:12:26.620: W/System.err(1359):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
12-12 07:12:26.620: W/System.err(1359):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-12 07:12:26.620: W/System.err(1359):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
12-12 07:12:26.620: W/System.err(1359):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-12 07:12:26.620: W/System.err(1359):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-12 07:12:26.620: W/System.err(1359):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
12-12 07:12:26.620: W/System.err(1359):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 07:12:26.620: W/System.err(1359):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-12 07:12:26.620: W/System.err(1359):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
12-12 07:12:26.620: W/System.err(1359):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
12-12 07:12:26.620: W/System.err(1359):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-12 07:12:26.620: W/System.err(1359): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-12 07:12:26.640: W/System.err(1359):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
12-12 07:12:26.640: W/System.err(1359):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
12-12 07:12:26.640: W/System.err(1359):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
12-12 07:12:26.640: W/System.err(1359):     ... 18 more
12-12 07:12:26.900: D/(1359): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb85fd238, tid 1359
12-12 07:12:26.950: W/EGL_emulation(1359): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-12 07:12:26.960: D/OpenGLRenderer(1359): Enabling debug mode 0
12-12 07:12:27.140: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1359): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
12-12 07:12:51.980: D/AndroidRuntime(1359): Shutting down VM
12-12 07:12:51.980: W/dalvikvm(1359): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a5bb90)
12-12 07:12:51.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1359): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 07:12:51.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1359): Process: com.example.def5ine, PID: 1359
12-12 07:12:51.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1359): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 07:12:51.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1359):     at com.example.def5ine.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:46)
12-12 07:12:51.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1359):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
12-12 07:12:51.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1359):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
12-12 07:12:51.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1359):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-12 07:12:51.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1359):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-12 07:12:51.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1359):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-12 07:12:51.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1359):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
12-12 07:12:51.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1359):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 07:12:51.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1359):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-12 07:12:51.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1359):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
12-12 07:12:51.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1359):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
12-12 07:12:51.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1359):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-12 07:13:03.090: I/Process(1359): Sending signal. PID: 1359 SIG: 9
```

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: try giving absolute path

Comment: @AniketThakur surely you'd want it on the classpath?

Comment: Did you check that `/android_asset/dictionary.json` exists?

Comment: Looks like you have the absolute path commented-out.  Was that not working?  Is the file readable (check permissions)?

Comment: Are you trying to access a file that is stored in the assets folder of your app?

Comment: the title is the question @BartFriederichs

Comment: i have alredy tried it @AniketThakur but it also raises the same exception.

Comment: yes It is Readable @EdgeCase

Comment: i have tried this method and worked, s=getAssets().open("dictionary.json"); but cant find the solution for absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE** Since the question have some views and I think it may help to other I am posting answer to my own question.

To Access the assets directory you have to prefix the file:/// in front of the directory name:

Which is in my case:

```
String pathToMyAssetDirectory="file:///android_asset/dictionary.json";
File file= new File(pathToMyAssetDirectory);
```

The other option to get the asset directory reference is using the applications Context as follows:

```
context.getResources().getAssets().open("fileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```